# WCF: Cannot Access a closed stream

Tags: c#, wcf, stream

I am trying to receive a Stream object in WCF but when i receive it i get a closed Stream.
Following is my code

```
[OperationContract]
string ProcessPackageUsingStream(FileStream stream, string fileName, string docType, string customerKey, int documentId);
```

in implementation i am using this stream object.

```
string ProcessPackageUsingStream(FileStream stream, string fileName, string docType, string customerKey, int documentId);
{
     //Stream is closed here
}
```

Here is my config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>

     <bindings>          
             <basicHttpBinding>
             <binding name="TransferService"   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed" >
                 <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
             <security mode="None"> 
             </security> 
           </binding>          
         </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
     <services>

         <service behaviorConfiguration="TransferServiceBehavior" name="TransferService">
              <endpoint  address=""
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransferService"
                contract ="ITransferService">
                         </endpoint>
          </service>
     </services>
     <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>

             <behavior name="TransferServiceBehavior">
                 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
               <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                 <serviceThrottling
                      maxConcurrentCalls="500"
                      maxConcurrentSessions="500"
                      maxConcurrentInstances="500"
                    />
             </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
     </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

On client side i have added reference to this service and used following code

```
SPCServiceClient service = new SPCServiceClient();
    service.ProcessPackageUsingStream(File.OpenRead(@"D:\Dev\TestData\002160500041.pdf"), "002160500041.pdf", "Test", "VLR@2016", 1211);
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having a similar issue currently.

Comment: @Jaans Yes i did. Following is solution which resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. Following solution worked for me. 
Instead of passing stream directly as parameter i created two classes one for passing parameters and other for getting response like:

```
[MessageContract]
    public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
    {
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string FileName;

        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string DocType;

        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string CustomerKey;

        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public string DocumentId;

        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (FileByteStream != null)
            {
                FileByteStream.Close();
                FileByteStream = null;
            }
        }
    }

[MessageContract]
public class RemoteResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Token;
}
```

Then i updated my method in WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
RemoteResponse ProcessPackageUsingStream(RemoteFileInfo remote);
```

And updated my app.config

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPreProcessor" transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth = "2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength = "2147483647"
            maxArrayLength = "2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead = "2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount = "2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```